# SharePoint 2010 - W3wp.exe consuming memory

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, worker-process

I am confronting a high memory consumption. By investigation, I found out that this dll is the reason: ONETUTIL!VlsaWrapper

Any idea?

Comment: How high? This is a standard .dll

Comment: As long as I perform an action, the Memory increases progressively and do not decrease until a recycle of the application pool is done.

Comment: What is the action that you are performing? The question is very light on information at this point.

Comment: The action is taken within a SharePoint feature that uses web services.